# idle script for storing start and end time the same python

Tags: python

i get the below code from internet and i edit on it to match my needs, I'm trying to make a software to get the idle time (start and end) and store them in a file the start and end time wrote the same. i need when idle time start it write the time and date and when user do move mouse or touch the keyboard the write the end time.
notes I'm  beginner of python.

```
import ctypes, ctypes.wintypes
from time import strftime


class LASTINPUTINFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
      ('cbSize', ctypes.wintypes.UINT),
      ('dwTime', ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
      ]

PLASTINPUTINFO = ctypes.POINTER(LASTINPUTINFO)


user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
GetLastInputInfo = user32.GetLastInputInfo
GetLastInputInfo.restype = ctypes.wintypes.BOOL
GetLastInputInfo.argtypes = [PLASTINPUTINFO]

kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
GetTickCount = kernel32.GetTickCount
Sleep = kernel32.Sleep

def wait_until_idle(idle_time=60):
idle_time_ms = int(idle_time*1000)
liinfo = LASTINPUTINFO()
liinfo.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(liinfo)
while True:
    GetLastInputInfo(ctypes.byref(liinfo))
    elapsed = GetTickCount() - liinfo.dwTime
    if elapsed>=idle_time_ms:
        break
    Sleep(idle_time_ms - elapsed or 1)

def wait_until_active(tol=5):
    liinfo = LASTINPUTINFO()
    liinfo.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(liinfo)
    lasttime = None
    delay = 1 # ms
    maxdelay = int(tol*1000)
    while True:
        GetLastInputInfo(ctypes.byref(liinfo))
        if lasttime is None: lasttime = liinfo.dwTime
        if lasttime != liinfo.dwTime:
            break
        delay = min(2*delay, maxdelay)
        Sleep(delay)

def idletime():
    string = strftime('%I:%M:%S %p ')
    string2 = strftime('%A  %d-%b-%Y')
    new_line = '\n'
    wait_until_idle(10)
    user32.MessageBeep(0)
    with open("D:\idle.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(new_line + string + string2 + ' Start')
    f.close()
    wait_until_active(1)
    user32.MessageBeep(0)
    with open("D:\idle.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(new_line + string + string2 + ' End')
    f.close()


if __name__=='__main__':
    idletime()
```

Answer (score 0):

The start and end time are same as both the variables are assigned one after another with no tasks/code in between to execute. The following change in the fuction `idletime` should fix the mentioned issue:

```
def idletime():
    string = strftime('%I:%M:%S %p ')
    string2 = strftime('%A  %d-%b-%Y')
    new_line = '\n'
    wait_until_idle(10)
    user32.MessageBeep(0)
    with open("D:\idle.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(new_line + string + string2 + ' Start')
    f.close()
    wait_until_active(1)
    user32.MessageBeep(0)
    
    string = strftime('%I:%M:%S %p ')
    string2 = strftime('%A  %d-%b-%Y')
    with open("D:\idle.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(new_line + string + string2 + ' End')
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Prashant Maurya for your answer
but it's not what i want 
i want 2 lins in my file on start and another end with same format date and time.
when idle time start and another when it finish

Comment: @MohamedHussein try the updated code

Comment: i already update 
it comes like this in a file 
03:42:43 PM  Start
Monday  20-Jun-2022 End
and my code wrote in a file like this 
04:01:09 PM Monday  20-Jun-2022 Start
04:01:09 PM Monday  20-Jun-2022 End
but it's wrote the same time

Comment: @MohamedHussein in your code you haven't updated the value of `string` & `string2` variables after it went from idle to active. Please pay attention, it should be updated twice, one at the start of the function and then in the end

Comment: i'll try it again and i'll tell you